# progressHUD with Cancel UIButton in iOS7 style

Tags: ios, ios7, progress, hud

I am looking for a ProgressHUD Framework with the possibility to cancel my upload process. 
Can you give me a hint, please!

Yours Raphael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out MRProgressHud on GitHub:

https://github.com/mrackwitz/MRProgress

Comment: No problem - glad you found it useful.